# React props to parent Component and inject props to this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to build a React component that renders a `<rect>` element and a `<text>` element, whereas the `<text>` element acts like the label of the `<rect>` one.

So far I've created the component, which can be used as follow:

```
<RectWithLabel x={} y={} width={} height={} labelColor={}>This is the label</RectWithLabel>
```

As you can see, `RectWithLabel` expects the props of a normal `<rect>` element, plus some other props to customize the label (e.g. `labelColor`).

Though, this implementation has lots of limitation, the most important one is that I cannot directly add props to the `<text>` element that is the label, unless I pass it to `RectWithLabel` and then to the `<text>` element it creates. The problem with this is that `RectWithLabel` already expect the `<rect>` props, so I may have overlapping props.

So, now that you know what I want to achieve, the question. I thought that the best solution would be to implement three Components: `ShapeWithLabel`, `RectShape` and `LabelShape`, to be used as follow:

```
<ShapeWithLabel>
  <RectShape x={} y={} width={} height={} ... />
  <LabelShape opacity={} transform={}>This is the label</LabelShape>
</ShapeWithLabel>
```

Basically, `ShapeWithLabel` expect two (or one, if the label will not be displayed) elements, one for the `<rect>` and one for the `<text>`.
Then, while `RectShape` expect the same props as it was a `<rect>` element, `LabelShape` expect the same props as it was a `<text>` element. Doing this way I could define different properties to the two elements easily.

But! The problem is also that in `ShapeWithLabel` I need store information about both children. For example, the label passed to `LabelShape` it's probably not the one that it will be displayed: the label may be ellipsed, so the actual label could be something like `"This is the l..."`.
Also, I need to position the label at the center of the rect, and to do so, I need to compute the `x` and `y` position of the label based on the `<rect>` element coordinates.

So, in `ShapeWithLabel` I would need to have the ref of both the `<rect>` and `<text>` elements created by `RectShape` and `LabelShape`. Moreover, I need to pass additional props to `LabelShape`, like the actual label and the label coordinates.

So, because how  the components would be used, the `render()` method of `ShapeWithLabel` would be just a simple `{this.props.children}` (I may check that the two children are one a `RectShape` and one a `LabelShape`, but that's it).

Can you guys help me figure this out? I'm really losing my mind about this.

Comment: it will be more easy if you put some code. and show what you have tried so far

Comment: Well, the implementation of `RectWithLabel` wouldn't be useful since it's not working like I would like the new Component to work. Instead, for the three new Components, actually I've no code at all since I don't know how I could achieve what I want >_>

Comment: Ok so both the children are siblings? and you need to pass the same properties for each of the child componenet? thats it.

Comment: Kinda.. I have a parent Component and two Children (thus, siblings). Each children receive props, but then, from those props, I need to make computation from the parent Component, and then pass custom props, from the parent, to the children (but the parent component, in render(), just renders this.props.children)

Comment: I would like to suggest you to pass a (arrow) function from the parent to child, and then pass the custom value from child to parent and then you can do the calculation you want.

Comment: Uhm and what about the ref? I need the ref of the elements rendered from the children component, but I need these ref in the parent

Comment: ref are not recommanded to use but if you don't have any other option which is not the case you can use it.